# How to disregard case when searching a txt document?

Tags: html, php, search

I have a search box on my website that searches from a list of websites (stored in `sites.txt`), the list looks like this:

```
<a href="example.org">Example Website</a>
<a href="example.com">Another Example Website</a>
```

The search box uses this action to find matching results from the list:

```
<?php
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$f = fopen("sites.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE) {
   if (strstr($line, $q)) {
       print "<p>$line</p>";
   }
}
?>
```

How can I change the PHP to make sure that the search box input's case is ignored?

I.E: search for 'another' returns 'Another Example Website'

Comment: Look at the manual page for [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) then go to the **see also section** and click on the link to the function described as **Case-insensitive strstr** i.e. [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if (strstr($line, $q)) {`

To make it case-insensitive, just change `strstr()` to use the `stristr()` (with an `i`) function instead.

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php